# How can i select the last li in this list using only css

Tags: css, css-selectors

I have a code generating segment  in a loop of varying li for every loop.  is it possible to select the last li of every loop using css only?

```
       <span class="card-title">November 19, 2015</span>
        <div class="cardseparator1"></div>
        <li>User FFDev has added 2 tasks</li>
        <li>User FFDev has added 3 forms</li>
        <li>User FFDev has added 1 users</li>
       <span class="card-title">November 18, 2015</span>
        <div class="cardseparator1"></div>
        <li>User FFDev has added 10 tasks</li>
        <li>User FFDev has added 8 forms</li>
        <li>User FFDev has added 4 assets to asset management</li>
        <li>User FFDev has added 4 users</li>
        <li>User null has updated 2 tasks</li>
        <li>User FFDev has updated 2 tasks</li>
        <li>User FFDev has updated 3 forms</li>
       <span class="card-title">November 17, 2015</span>
        <div class="cardseparator1"></div>
        <li>User FFDev has added 1 tasks</li>
        <li>User FFDev has added 3 forms</li>
        <li>User FFDev has added 1 users</li>
        <li>User FFDev has updated 2 assets to asset management</li>
       <span class="card-title">November 16, 2015</span>
        <div class="cardseparator1"></div>
        <li>User FFDev has added 1 tasks</li>
        <li>User FFDev has added 2 users</li>
       <span class="card-title">November 12, 2015</span>
        <div class="cardseparator1"></div>
        <li>User FFDev has added 1 geofence settings</li>
```

Comment: Your html is completely invalid, `li`s nee to be a child of `ol` or `ul` and then you can just use `li:last-child`

Comment: It is a generated. I can't do anything about it. Because of that i can't use last-child or last-of-type selector!

Comment: I would fix whatever is generating it

Answer (score 0):

```
.cardseparator1 li:last-of-type { ... }
```

Use `last-of-type` - there's also `first-of-type` and many more e.g. `nth-of-type`

Comment: Sorry, just edited the question. cardseparator1 and li is in the same ranks.

Answer (score 0):

```
.cardseparator1 li:nth-last-child(1) {
        background: #ff0000;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
.cardseparator1  li:last-of-type {
    background: red;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use like this below code,

```
li:last-child {
background: #ff0000;}
```

or 
code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style> 
li:last-child {
background: #ff0000;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<li>1</li>
<li>2</li>
<li>3</li>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: 1. i'm not writing the code. it's generated. 2.Last-child selects the last li not  the last li in the loop.

Answer (score 0):

none of the methods will work with css unless your code is not valid with proper nesting of `<li>` within `<ul>` or `<ol>` like the code below I am also posting Fiddle of how to achieve it..

[Working Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ManojSalvi/2xcfcyov/)

**CODE**

```
<span class="card-title">November 19, 2015</span>
        <div class="cardseparator1"></div>
<ul class="custom-class">
        <li>User FFDev has added 2 tasks</li>
        <li>User FFDev has added 3 forms</li>
        <li>User FFDev has added 1 users</li>
</ul>
       <span class="card-title">November 18, 2015</span>
        <div class="cardseparator1"></div>
<ul class="custom-class">
        <li>User FFDev has added 10 tasks</li>
        <li>User FFDev has added 8 forms</li>
        <li>User FFDev has added 4 assets to asset management</li>
        <li>User FFDev has added 4 users</li>
        <li>User null has updated 2 tasks</li>
        <li>User FFDev has updated 2 tasks</li>
        <li>User FFDev has updated 3 forms</li>
</ul>
       <span class="card-title">November 17, 2015</span>
        <div class="cardseparator1"></div>
<ul class="custom-class">
        <li>User FFDev has added 1 tasks</li>
        <li>User FFDev has added 3 forms</li>
        <li>User FFDev has added 1 users</li>
        <li>User FFDev has updated 2 assets to asset management</li>
</ul>
       <span class="card-title">November 16, 2015</span>
        <div class="cardseparator1"></div>
<ul class="custom-class">
        <li>User FFDev has added 1 tasks</li>
        <li>User FFDev has added 2 users</li>
</ul>
       <span class="card-title">November 12, 2015</span>
        <div class="cardseparator1"></div>
<ul class="custom-class">
        <li>User FFDev has added 1 geofence settings</li>

</ul>
```

**CSS**

```
.custom-class li:last-child {
    color:red;
}
```